# Celery inspect worker tasks and retrieve the task docstrings

Tags: django, celery

I'm working with a celery worker node and developing a Django Rest API to handle celery task submission. I can get a list of tasks through inspect()

```
     i = app.control.inspect()
     i.registerd()
```

But need to get the docstring from worker node tasks. This will be used for the GET request to display useful helpful information to end user. The Celery task code is not install within the django rest api application. So how to inspect tasks on worker and return the docstring for task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `__doc__` on your tasks?

Comment: I could use __ doc __ but the code is not available locally. Celery uses brokers which communicate to worker nodes. The application connects to the brooker and through Celery you can inspect registered tasks. The problem is that I cannot find a method to pull the docstring from the worker node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype of **registered** is

```
def registered(self, *taskinfoitems): 
    return self._request('dump_tasks', taskinfoitems=taskinfoitems)
```

You could specify `__doc__` in the **taskinfoitems** parameter